# How to define Squeryl schemas for two different db in Play

Tags: playframework-2.0, squeryl

I'd like to add a second temporary DB (filebased H2) to our Play 2.1 app. But can't figure out how and where to create a Squeryl schema for the second DB.

The first schema is already defined in a scala class that extends org.squeryl.Schema. Where should I put table definitions for the second DB?

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: By digging around, I found a hint in the Squeryl Google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/squeryl/kdUmp1-hOmA - I guess I need to create a different Schema class and override Schema.name attribute. Still not sure how to tell Squeryl which schema to use for what DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used Play so you may need to tweak this around a bit to get it to work, but you should be able to create a new session for that database, something like:

```
object MySecondDBSchema extends SquerylSchema with SchemaDefaults {
  def newSession[A](f: => A) =  {
    transaction(new org.squeryl.Session(//get java.sql.Connection, new H2Adapter)) {
      f
    }
  }

  val myTable = table[MyTable]
}
```

or, if you just want a connection and plan to deal with transactions on your own.

```
def newSession[A](f: => A) =  {
  using(new org.squeryl.Session(//get java.sql.Connection, new H2Adapter)) {
    //start your own transaction
    f
  }
}
```

Then in your code, when you want to access that other database you can wrap your queries in that:

```
def myMethodToAccessFirstDB() = {
  import MySecondDBSchema._

  newSession{ 
    //access alternate database
    from(myTable)(t => select(t)).toList 
  }
}

def myMethodToAccessDefaultDB() = {
  import DefaultSchema._ //Or whatever your default Schema is named

  //access default database
  from(otherTable)(ot => select(ot))
}
```

It is logical to define and organize the tables in a second object that extends `org.squeryl.Schema` but any query made within the `newSession` block will be performed against the second database.

As for overriding the `name` attribute, that will change the default [schema in the database](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_schema) but is not necessary for creating a separate Squeryl schema.

Comment: @jcem - thanks. My question was about creating a second schema and binding that schema to the second DB, not about the sessions. I sort of figured out the session part. In any case, is it a good practice to create a new Session for each H2 query? Should I better cache it somewhere (in Play Cache, for instance)?

Comment: Sorry, I may have understood. Do you want to create a second schema on the existing database - like: `db.schema1.tablename` and `db.schema2.tablename` or are you looking to use a second, separate database together with your existing one? If the latter, then what I posted would apply. If the former, then you were on the right track - you would just import both Squeryl Schema's and query against your table definitions (just watch out for namespace conflicts). The question seemed to mention two separate DBs, which was why I answered the way I did.

Comment: @jcem: the latter - a separate database along with existing one. The second database should have a completely different schema. And I still don't get how to tell Squeryl to use another `Schema` class for the second DB.

Comment: @Alex, I updated the example to provide a bit of a more complete example. Let me know if that makes more sense.

Comment: thanks! That's exactly I was looking for. Somehow I didn't get that I can use appropriate imports or fully qualified names for the tables. Answer accepted!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to jcern answer: don't forget to close connection.
My variant:

```
object MySecondDBSchema extends Schema {

  var ds : DataSource = _

  def newSession[A](f: => A) = {
    var conn: Option[Connection] = None
    try {
      conn = Some(ds.getConnection)
      val proxyConn = conn.map {
        case a : ArraySupportProxyConnection => a
        case c : C3P0ProxyConnection => new ArraySupportProxyConnection(c)
      }.get
      using[A](new org.squeryl.Session(proxyConn, new AwesomePostgreSqlAdapter)) {
        inTransaction {
          f
        }
      }
    }
    finally {
      conn.foreach(_.close())
    }
  }

  ...
}
```